# How to refresh token with library " PHP-Open-Source-Saver / jwt-auth" in laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-9

I'm making an API in laravel and I wanted to create a refresh token routine.

I used the example from the website

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }
}
```

but it shows these errors
"Undefined method 'factory'.intelephense(1013)"
"Undefined method 'refresh'.intelephense(1013)"

How to do this refresh token routine? and why this error happened, in old versions, when JWT library was still tymondesigns/jwt-auth, this error didn't happen.

Laravel 9
PHP 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to refresh the token

```
$token = JWTAuth::getToken();
$new_token = JWTAuth::refresh($token);
```

However if you want the token to refresh on every request(discouraged) add the jwt.refresh middleware in your app\Http\Kernel.php to be

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'jwt.auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken',
    'jwt.refresh' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken',
];
```